# how to access UI elements of one viewcontroller from an objective c class?

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my application i have some view controllers and one objective c class ,how can i access the UI elemets of one view controller to change their values in objective class .

To explain further , i have a UILable *lab in the firstviewcontroller and just imported

`#import "firstViewController.h"`

in my **customclass.m** file  and i am trying to do like this in one method of objective c class

```
 firstViewController.lab.text=@"example";
```

( i know its not correct method but i am trying to explain what i am doing )

can any one please tell me how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to do is grab a reference to the view controller you wish to operate on.  One way to do this and have it available to other classes is to store a reference to it in a singleton object that you instantiate in your customclass.m.  Specifically this is how this method works:

Define Singleton Object:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MySingleton : NSObject {
     MyViewController *myViewController;

}
@propery (nonatomic. retain) MyViewController *myViewController;
+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton;

@implementation MySingleton
@synthesize myViewController;
static MySingleton* _sharedMySingleton = nil;

+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingleton)
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedMySingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMySingleton = [super alloc];
        return _sharedMySingleton;
    }

    return nil;
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialize stuff here
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Whereever you instantiate your myViewController you do this:

```
#import "MySingleton.h"

MySingleton *sinlgeton = [MySingleton sharedMySingleton];
singleton.myViewController = myViewController;
```

Now in your CustomClass.m you do this:

```
#import "MySingleton.h"

    MySingleton *sinlgeton = [MySingleton sharedMySingleton];
    singleton.myViewController.lab.text = @"example"
```

As I said this is ONE WAY to do this.  However, you most probably DO NOT want to access and change view controller properties in a custom class so you should really rethink why you are doing this at all.

Comment: thanks for reply , in my app in my singleton there is some method (related to asihttprequest) in that i am starting the request as asychronus and in the requestfinished delegate i need some info life how the process going like its in step1 ,step1 passed or step1failed i am trying to display them in one of view controller.I tried like assigning the changes to some variables and then fetching them to my viewcontroller using shared method but ,its not grabing the data instantly as i dont know how much time it take to go to requestfinish deleagte and do the next things ,i thought using while(1)

Comment: contd : .. to trigger when those variables change and display them here ,but i thought its simple and dirty idea thats why i am trying in other away . is there any problem in accessing UIelements from singleton class in terms of stability or speed ?

Answer (score 0):

As with most programming tasks there are several solutions and it depends on the situation.

You can have FirstViewController own the instance of the MyCustomClass and then pass itself.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
 MyCustomClass *customClass_;
}
@end

@implementation FirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 customClass_ = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init]
 customClass_.firstViewController = self;
}
@end

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject {
 FirstViewController *firstViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
@end
```

This way MyCustomClass can access the properties of FirstViewController. If you don't want to give MyCustomClass access to all of FirstViewController you can use pass along the properties that MyCustomClass should know about.

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
 MyCustomClass *customClass_;
 UILabel *lab;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lab;
@end

@implementation FirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 customClass_ = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init]
 customClass_.lab = self.lab;
}
@end

@interface MyCustomClass : NSObject {
 UILabel *lab;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lab;
@end
```

It could very well be the case that it doesn't make sense for FirstViewController to be the owner of MyCustomClass. Perhaps it is the AppDelegate or some parent controller that have access to both instances.

```
@interface RandomParentClass : NSObject {
 FirstViewController *firstViewController;
 MyCustomClass *customClass:
}
@end

@implementation RandomParentClass 

- (void)setUpController {
 firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
 customClass = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init];
 customClass.lab = firstViewController.lab;
 // or
 customClass.firstViewController = firstViewController;
}

@end
```